# Updating variables with sympy

Tags: python, analytics, sympy, symbols, symbolic-math

I have a problem with sympy where it won't update my values. So I'm trying to do an iterative method for solving $\sigma_x$ and when I try to put numerical values into my expression it won't update.

I have imported sympy as sy
So I first have this code:

```
q,b,E,t,nu,L,z,x,y = sy.symbols("q,b,E,t,nu,L,z,x,y") 
D = (E*t**3)/(12*(1-nu**2)) 
q_0 = 4*q/(sy.pi*b) * sy.sin(sy.pi/2)*(1-sy.cos(sy.pi)) 
D2 = (sy.pi**2 / L**2) + (sy.pi**2 / b**2) 
w = q_0/(D* D2**2) * sy.sin(sy.pi*x/L) * sy.sin(sy.pi * y / b) 
M = 4 
N = 4 
w_iterert = 0 
for m in range(1,M+1):
     for n in range(N+1):
         q_iterert = 4*q/(sy.pi*b*m)*sy.sin(sy.pi*n/2)*(1-sy.cos(sy.pi*m))
         w_mn = q_iterert/(D*((sy.pi**2*m**2 / L**2) + (sy.pi**2 * n**2 / b**2))**2)
         w_iterert += w_mn*sy.sin(m*pi*x/L)*sy.sin(n*pi*y/b)
```

Then I plot the analytical expression:

```
w_iterert
```

And now I use formulas to find my sigma_x:

```
w_xx_iter = sy.diff(w_iterert,x,2) 
w_yy_iter = sy.diff(w_iterert,y,2) 
sigma_x_iter = - z*E/(1-nu**2)*(w_xx_iter+nu*w_yy_iter)
```

Here is where I get it wrong. now I do this:

```
E = 210000 
pi = sy.pi 
q = 20 
nu = 0.3 
L = 4000 
b = 1000  
t = 10 
x = 2 
z = t/2 
y = b/2 
sigma_x_iter
```

And I would expect this to update the values and give me the numerical value. Instead I just get the same analytical expression. How can I update my values?

I tried everything, I just wrote and tried to copy the text into another notebook which obviously worked. But then I can't change the M N values and get a different result unless I do it automatically.

Comment: I think you need to study the `sympy` tutorial more.  Specifically https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols.  You created symbols and assigned them to Python variables.  Reassigning those variables looses the connection between the variables and symbols.  You have to use `subs` to assign values to the symbols.

Comment: If you try this with my problem you find out this wont work beacuse it treats the numerics as symbols and tries to derivate w.r.t 2000

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit your code several times to get something that I could copy-n-paste and run.

What I meant by `subs` is:

```
In [38]: sigma_x_iter.subs({E:210000, q:20,nu:0.3,L:4000,b:1000,t:10,x:2,z:10/2,
    ...:  y:1000/2})
Out[38]: 
        ⎛                      ⎛ π  ⎞                       ⎛3⋅π ⎞⎞           
        ⎜654766080000000000⋅sin⎜────⎟   9844326400000000⋅sin⎜────⎟⎟           
        ⎜                      ⎝2000⎠                       ⎝2000⎠⎟           
2.0e-10⋅⎜──────────────────────────── + ──────────────────────────⎟   9.6e-10⋅
        ⎝           243049                         2601           ⎠           
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + ────────
                                  3                                           
                                 π                                            

⎛                    ⎛3⋅π ⎞                         ⎛ π  ⎞⎞
⎜1321369600000000⋅sin⎜────⎟   725790720000000000⋅sin⎜────⎟⎟
⎜                    ⎝2000⎠                         ⎝2000⎠⎟
⎜────────────────────────── + ────────────────────────────⎟
⎝           2601                         243049           ⎠
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                          3                                
                         π                                 

In [39]: _38.n()
Out[39]: 0.361692509661739
```

In `sympy` you need to keep a clear distinction between a symbol, and the variable that references it.  `sympy` works within the Python environment, without changing syntax.  You may need to study the documented `gotachas` some more.

`E` as defined is a symbol:

```
In [42]: type(E)
Out[42]: sympy.core.symbol.Symbol
```

This assignment assigns an int to `E`, breaking any connection it had with the symbol.  The symbol still exists in the various expressions, but you can no longer reference it with the variable `E`.  This assignment does not touch any of the expressions.

```
In [43]: E = 210000

In [44]: type(E)
Out[44]: int
```